# PythonでPhantomJSが使えない

Tags: python, linux, phantomjs

python3.4
PhantomJS 2.1.1
selenium 3.0.2
OS X 10.10.5

$which phantomjs 
/usr/local/bin/phantomjs

$phantomjs 
phantomjs>（起動してる。。？）
となっております。

<strike>PhantomJSは/usr/local/bin/phantomjsにあり、</strike>。
<strike>PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/phantomjsでパスが通るようにしました。</strike>  。

現在、下記のコードを実行するとエラーが出てしまいます。
なにか考えられる原因などはありますでしょうか？
かなり初歩的な質問になってしまうと思いますが、どうぞよろしく御願いいたします。

```
import lxml.html
from selenium import webdriver

target_url = '~~~~~~~'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(target_url)
```

> ```
>       Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
>       stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py",
>   line 859, in __init__
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py",
>   line 1463, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] **No such file or directory: 'phantomjs'**
>  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/Users/kojisugano/Documents/python/動的ページ＿スクレイピング.py", line 5, in <module>      
>    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs ')
>  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
> self.service.start()
>  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
> os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs ' executable needs to be in PATH.
> ```

下記の質問によるとexecutable_pathを書いたり、pythonの下にphantomjsを入れています。ネット上のほとんどの方は、PATHを通してexecutable_pathを書かずに利用していますが、こちらの下記の質問のようなやり方がいいのでしょうか？？

```
webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="~~~~~")
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869757/selenium-phantomjs-raises-error

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` なのでは?

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。それはphantomjsにパスが通ってないという事でしょうか?念のためecho $PATHで確認してみましたが、パスは通っているんです。

Comment: 環境にもよるかも知れませんが、`homebrew`でPhantomJSを入れてみてはいかがでしょう。

Comment: @KojiSugano パスが通っているかどうかの確認には `which phantomjs` としてください。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。ターミナル上でwhich phantomjs の結果は/usr/local/bin/phantomjsになり、MAC:~ ユーザー名$ phantomjsの結果、phantomjsは起動できます。Linuxの勉強をもうちょっとした方が良さそうですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 質問文の編集でエラー内容を追記されているようですが、その中の `executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs '` という部分、`phantomjs` の後ろに空白があるのですが、コピペミスですか?